# Gradle daemon listens on all interfaces by default

Tags: ip, server, ports

Was messing around with a project today that uses the build tool Gradle and I noticed that **by default**, it's running a daemon server process that listens on all interfaces.

Output of `ss` below.

```
State   Recv-Q   Send-Q           Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
LISTEN  0        50                           *:37367                  *:*       users:(("java",pid=25378,fd=211))
```

Behind the NAT of my home router, I don't have to worry about being bombarded on this open port, but when I'm on campus (where I'm assigned a public IP), Gradle will actually open connections to whoever tries to connect to that port.

Is this correct? If so, it's seems absolutely crazy to me that Gradle's default configuration would listen on all interfaces. Unless it's an extremely simple server and they're super confident it won't get expoited I guess.

Couldn't find any mention of this in their documentation.

Comment: Gradle is a service that is meant to be available on the network.

Comment: Ok, as someone that's only using it build applications locally (and doesn't know much about gradle), I was quite surprised to see it listening on all interfaces by default. Still not quite sure why it needs to do that. I feel that most applications default to localhost or unix sockets unless specified otherwise, e.g., `dockerd`.

Comment: docker is not intended to be available on the network. As with any computer you use, you should have a firewall that only allows access to the services that you have approved. That way any service could listen on any interface and your risks are mitigated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a computer without a firewall that only allows access to approved services, then yes, anyone on your local network could connect to this service.

The developers of a service do not have to assume that their service is not vulnerable. They only need to assume that the people running their service have a minimum of security on the machine where it is run.

If something has an API, it typically exposes that API to the network in some way. This certainly was not always true, but it is the norm now. So the mention of an API is usually a clue that a service gets exposed.